# Cannot access 'X' before initialization

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, class, extends

I am trying to create a child class in my parent class like this :

```
class Stage {
    a() {
        return new ChestStage();
    }
}
```

And the child class :

```
 class ChestStage extends Stage {
     constructor(){
        super();
     }
}
```

But I got this error : `Unhandled Promise rejection: Cannot access 'XModule' before initialization ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: ReferenceError: Cannot access 'XModule' before initialization`

I know that the error is coming from the extends, because when I remove it, it's working. But I don't have any idea how to fix it. If you have any ideas, it'll be great.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Lets say `a ()` method is written in `ChestStage` directly and not by heritance from `Stage`. It will be looking as the following:

```js
class ChestStage {
  a () {
    return new ChestStage();
  }
}
```

That means you are trying to create an instance of `ChestStage` within method of `ChestStage` itself... That's impossible.